# Restore RAID 1 Centos without losing data

Tags: centos, raid

someone could provide a complete guide on how to synchronize a RAID 1 with 2 HD 1TB.

The situation is the following:

```
# cat /proc/mdstat

Personalities : [linear] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [multipath] [faulty]
md2 : active raid1 sdb2[1]
      20478912 blocks [2/1] [_U]

md3 : active raid1 sdb3[1]
      1932506048 blocks [2/1] [_U]
      bitmap: 15/15 pages [60KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>

# fdisk -l

WARNING: fdisk GPT support is currently new, and therefore in an experimental phase. Use at your own discretion.

Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: gpt


#         Start          End    Size  Type            Name
 1           40         2048  1004,5K  BIOS boot parti primary
 2         4096     40962047   19,5G  Linux RAID      primary
 3     40962048   3905974271    1,8T  Linux RAID      primary
 4   3905974272   3907020799    511M  Linux swap      primary

Disk /dev/sda: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/md3: 1978.9 GB, 1978886193152 bytes, 3865012096 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/md2: 21.0 GB, 20970405888 bytes, 40957824 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

I did not want to proceed independently because I would be sure not to delete the data.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Take (and test) a backup and then you won't have to worry about this at all.

Comment: Surely this has been described a thousand times over already, such a basic operation... Step 1 duplicate the fdisk config on the new disk, step 2 use `mdadm -a /dev/mdX /dev/sdaX` to add the appropriate partition to the md device, repeat for the other md devices.